# Get current label placement when using text-variable-anchor in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

The mapbox-gl-js library allows you to set a styling property, `text-variable-anchor`, to variably orient a text label around a point so it avoids collisions. But is there a way to get the current state of a label to know where Mapbox decided to place it?

We're using variable placement but also have some UI that depends on the current label placement for positioning. If I find the feature with `queryRenderedFeatures` there's nothing in there related to it's current position. Is there some other way to find it? Or should this be a feature request for mapbox-gl?